# Can the PowerShell -match operator be used to test version strings?

Tags: regex, powershell, match, version

I want to use PowerShell to check the OS version. The script is like this:

```
$a = "6.3.9600"
$a -match "6.0"
```

I run this script on the PowerShell ISE and this script returns `$true`.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your specific use case of testing a version string, .NET provides a [`Version` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version) that can be useful here.  You can create an instance like this...

```
$version = [Version] $a
```

...or like this...

```
$version = [Version]::Parse($a)
```

There are properties for the major version, minor version, build, and revision...

```
PS> $version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      3      9600   -1
```

You can then perform tests like this...

```
PS> $version.Major -eq 6
True
PS> $version.Major -eq 6 -and $version.Minor -eq 3
True
PS> $version.Major -eq 6 -and $version.Minor -ge 3
True
PS> $version.Major -eq 6 -and $version.Minor -gt 3
False
```

Comment: Good idea that this is what I really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

powershell can use the dotnet `[version]` type accelerator for this. it understands version numbers, so it knows that `6.0.9.1` is less than `6.0.11.1`. here's a demo ...

```
$FoundVersion = [version]'6.3.9600'
$WantedVersion = [version]'6.0'

'Is it greater or equal? = {0}' -f ($FoundVersion -ge $WantedVersion)
'Is it equal?            = {0}' -f ($FoundVersion -eq $WantedVersion)
```

output ...

```
Is it greater or equal? = True
Is it equal?            = False
```

Comment: This didn't answer the powershell match usage. But it does exactly answer what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AaronHu - yep, your use of `-match` seemed to be a very roundabout way to get the answer - once one knows about the `[version]` type accelerator. i saw that you already had an answer about the way regex treats dots. you are most welcome! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell -match is a regular expression match, in which a period `.` matches any character. So for your code:

```
$a = "6.3.9600"
$a -match "6.0"
```

The match is found, as `"600"` 'matches' `"6.0"`.

If you want to search for period specifically, you need to escape it, by replacing it with `\.`:

```
"600" -match "6.0"
True
"600" -match "6\.0"
False

$a = "6.3.9600"
$a -match "6\.0"
False
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to anchor the match to the beginning of the input string, too, with `^6\.0` so as to not match, for example, version `6.6.0` should one ever be released.

Comment: This is the answer for match. I forgot that the match use regx... Thanks a lot.